# Play! framework - accessing a "private" file

Tags: java, io, playframework, playframework-2.0, filereader

in my website there's a certain page for administration. when you load the page, it suppose to parse a `csv file`. I encountered with two problems:

1. where should the file be located. I don't want it to be on `public` because then anyone could read it.
2. virtually, what the page does is reading the csv file using `FileReader` class. what should be the path to the file?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deploy your CSV you could store it in the home folder:

Use the Java class File: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(home + File.separator + "aFile.csv");
```

To read a small file you can use apache fileutils:

```
String fileContents = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html
(may be add a dependency)

Comment: You should use ``File.separator`` instead of ``File.pathSeparator``. On Windows ``File.pathSeparator`` would be **;**.